# Jquery and Get traversing API

Tags: javascript, jquery, splice

Is there a simple way to get a node list (including the given node) matched by a query with Jquery?

I thought about using the .find method as following:

```
var getNodes = function(dom, query){
    var nodes = $(dom).find(query || '*');
    nodes.splice(0,0,dom);
    return nodes;
}
```

Olivier

Comment: What do you mean by the "node list including the given node"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to search inside a set made of `dom` and its contents for elements matching a query, then you can do

```
$(dom).find(query).add($(dom).filter(query))
```

or

```
$(dom).find(query).addBack().filter(query);
```

A simpler one (but slower if there are many children) would be

```
$(dom).find('*').addBack().filter(query);
```

Comment: You probably meant `.addBack()` :)

Comment: @kidwon Yes, I was disturbed because of the replacement of `andSelf` by `addBack`... :)

Comment: In my opinion the `andSelf` name is the better one

Answer (score 0):

The result of `$()` anything in jQuery is an instance of `jQuery` not a JavaScript array. What you could do is something like this:

```
var nodes = [ dom ];
var found = $(dom).find(query || '*');
$.each(found, function(item) { nodes.push(this); });
```